# Can a postgres autovacuum increase the TOAST size of the table?

Tags: postgresql, table, database-size

A table toast size goes from 7.5Go to 9.2Go in one hour. The normal database activity seems not responsible for that: no more queries than usual. To be the cause, it would need a larger amount of additional requests than we support.

The single match is an auto vacuum that ran sooner.

Is it possible a table toast size becomes bigger after an auto vacuum, for some reason?

[image: table size match death rows reduction]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in PostgreSQL `VACUUM` never increases the size of a TOAST table. Try to figure out what these figures actually measure.

The temporal coincidence might point to a different causality: a number of `UPDATE`s may have somewhat inflated the TOAST table and triggered autovacuum on the actual table (but not on the TOAST table).